# How do I get at the text inside this anchor tag with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If I have a link like this:

```
<ul id="main">
 <li>
    <a href="/login">Sign In</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

How do I retrieve the text **`Sign In`** with jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `text` method. Example:

```
var txt = $('#main li a').text();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is useful for grabbing the text based on the hyperlink URI:

```
  var linkText = $('a[href="/login"]').text();
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 3):

If that's actually the only text, you can get it direclty from the `#main` element. No need to drill down to the `<a>` element.

```
$('#main').text();
```

Though you may want to trim it.

```
$.trim( $('#main').text() );
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/GqKaN/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach, which selects the anchor by its href attribute:

```
$("#main a[href=/login]").text()
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $('#main li:first-child a:first-child').text();
```

Or without `:first-child` depending on your overall structure.

Reference: [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)